# Start hadoop cluster from php

Tags: php, shell, hadoop, ssh

I want to start my Hadoop cluster through php. **Note:** Hadoop server starts properly without any error when started from terminal via `start-all.sh` also have added ssh key to the machine(tejas@192.168.1.104) also have added tejas as a user to apache.
My php script is :

`shell_exec('/home/tejas/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh');`

the script throws error `starting namenode, logging to /home/tejas/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop--namenode-tejas.out 192.168.1.104: Host key verification failed. 192.168.1.104: Host key verification failed. jobtracker running as process 20020. Stop it first. 192.168.1.104: Host key verification failed.` Failed and does not start any service.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what is in your start script.

Comment: start-all.sh is the command to start hadoop cluster, and `(/home/tejas/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh) ` is only the path to start-all.sh in Hadoop directory.

Comment: Yeah, but we still need to know what exactly your script is doing.

Comment: php script or start-all.sh script?? contents of start-all.sh 
**# Start all hadoop daemons.  Run this on master node.
bin=`dirname "$0"`
bin=`cd "$bin"; pwd`
if [ -e "$bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh" ]; then
  . "$bin"/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh
else
  . "$bin/hadoop-config.sh"
fi
# start dfs daemons
"$bin"/start-dfs.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR
# start mapred daemons
"$bin"/start-mapred.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR**.   If there is any other way to start hadoop cluster through php then please suggest

Comment: This is the error I am getting **starting namenode, logging to /home/tejas/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop--namenode-tejas.out 192.168.1.104: Host key verification failed. 192.168.1.104: Host key verification failed. jobtracker running as process 20020. Stop it first. 192.168.1.104: Host key verification failed.**